# How to get state of 2D-Array in floating point Number

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to get the `state` of an array in floating point number.I'm getting it in string format.

For Example,I pass 2D-Array of `string` type and get state in `string` format.

**What do I need to make changes in my code?**

```
public string TwoDimensionalArrayToStringState(string[,] array)
{
   string state = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
      {
         state += array[i, j].ToString();
      }
   }
   return state;
}
```

It's working fine with state of type `string` for training of agent using Q-Learning algorithm with Q-Table.But now, I want to train Neural network to give input(state and action) of float type while output is a learning Q-Value.That's why I need to convert `state` in `float` type.
For more information,check this [link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10461/how-to-convert-q-matrix-to-artificial-neural-network) where I have asked my question with respect to AI. But now I want a little help with respect to code.
Any help appreciate?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by `state`. In the code you've posted it is the result of concatenating all strings in the array. Doing this with floating point numbers might result with an overflow exception.

Comment: @Johnny consider 2D-array as Q-Matrix.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  state in code is taken as string that is state of a matrix or 2D-Array while it presents state of an agent.As agent takes an action then its position will be changed in state that forms new state.

Comment: I don't want to sum elements @Johnny because it forms the state of string.
Consider when someone travel on x-axis then x-values are changed while traveling that gives states or new states and those values are evaluated in float.I want this conversion into this form of example.